# For.. in loop not adding attributes to Django object

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a new database object for the following Django class:

```
class MenuItems(models.Model):
    """Main class for food & drink menu items"""

    category = models.ForeignKey(MenuCategories, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=1)
    calories = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    proteins = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=1,
        null=True)
    carbs = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=1,
        null=True)
    sugar = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=1,
        null=True)
    fat = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=1,
        null=True)
    saturated_fat = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,
        decimal_places=1, null=True)
    sodium = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=1,
        null=True)
```

I start by fetching the category object using a custom function, this has been tested and works successfully. As you are able to see in the class definition, the only required fields are 'category', 'name' and 'price'. I send the following dictionary to the function which creates the database object:

```
details = {
    'category': category,
    'name': 'Pizza Hawaii',
    'price': 12,
    'entered_details': {
        'calories': 764,
        'proteins': 30.4,
        'carbs': 19.3,
        'sugar': 16.7,
        'fat': 29.6,
        'saturated_fat': 9.6,
        'sodium': 1560,
        }
    }
```

This is the code which should add all the entered values and most importantly, the optional values only if they are provided, to the object:

```
item = MenuItems.objects.create(
        category=details['category'],
        name=details['name'],
        price=details['price'],
    )
item.save()

for detail, value in details['entered_details'].items():
    item.detail = value
item.save()
```

When I try to call an optional value, such as 'calories' using

```
print(item.calories)
```

I get 'None'. All optional values are also saved in the database as Null. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `setattr` to set the attribute from the strings, not use dot access:

```
for detail, value in details['entered_details'].items():
    setattr(item, detail, value)
item.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

firstly it looks like you are just over writing the variable name 'item.detail = value' each loop without saving the item. Secondly, why loop when you know all the values already, just add them in like the start so something like

```
item = MenuItems.objects.create(
    category=details['category'],
    name=details['name'],
    price=details['price'],
    calories = details['entered_details']['calories'],
    proteins = details['entered_details']['proteins'],
    etc.....
)
item.save()
```

You could do the same with the loop. but just seems unnecessary. Hope this helps.

Comment: the final `item.save()` call is useless here - `objects.create()` do create the record in the database.

Comment: The reason I am using a loop is because 'calories' and 'proteins' are optional values and they will not be added to all the objects. If I would define them in the objects.create() I will get a KeyError if I send a dictionary to the function that doesn't contain an optional value.